# How to expand a data.frame according to one of its columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, match

What's an elegant way (without additional packages) to "expand" a given `data.frame` according to one of its columns?

Given:

```
df  <- data.frame(values = 1:5, strings = c("e", "g", "h", "b", "c"))
more.strings <- letters[c(3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 8, 6)]
```

Desired outcome: A `data.frame` containing:

```
5  c
1  e
2  g
NA a
NA d
3  h
NA f
```

So those values of `df$strings` appearing in `more.strings` should be used to fill the new `data.frame` (otherwise NA).

Comment: isn't it just `match` ? `match(more.strings, df$strings)` ? To get your desired output `data.frame(mat = match(more.strings, df$strings), more.strings)`.

Comment: right, `df[match(more.strings, df$strings), ]` is fine. Not sure why I didn't see this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this without using any library i.e. using only `base R`

```
data.frame(value = with(df, match(more.strings, strings)), 
        strings = more.strings)
#    value strings
#1     5       c
#2     1       e
#3     2       g
#4    NA       a
#5    NA       d
#6     3       h
#7    NA       f
```

---

Or we can use `complete`

```
library(tidyverse)
complete(df, strings = more.strings) %>% 
     arrange(match(strings, more.strings)) %>%
     select(names(df))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  values strings
#   <int> <chr>  
#1      5 c      
#2      1 e      
#3      2 g      
#4     NA a      
#5     NA d      
#6      3 h      
#7     NA f
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do a `join`:

In base R you could do:

```
merge(df, more.strings, by.y="y",by.x="strings", all.y=TRUE)
 strings values
1       c      5
2       e      1
3       g      2
4       h      3
5       a     NA
6       d     NA
7       f     NA
```

or even as given by @thelatemailin the comment section below:

```
 merge(df, list(strings=more.strings),by="strings", all.y=TRUE)
```

Using library:

```
library(tidyverse)
right_join(df,data.frame(strings=more.strings),by="strings")
  values strings
1      5       c
2      1       e
3      2       g
4     NA       a
5     NA       d
6      3       h
7     NA       f
```

Comment: Absolutely. Same works in `merge` - `merge(df, list(strings=more.strings), by="strings", all.y=TRUE)`

Comment: yes yes.. tru you can even use `merge(df, more.strings, by.y="y",by.x="strings", all.y=TRUE)`

Comment: Never saw the comment **Without additional package**

Comment: Thanks. Let me just add that there are several good reasons to do things without loading additional packages (for example, to avoid dependencies). This may or may not be wanted on stackoverflow, but I think the three words don't add much 'overhead' and some answers are not as useful if they require additional dependencies.